# Possible to delete dependent classes

Tags: apex, class, delete

We remarked a little strange issue in APEX. It is possible to remove a class, which is called in another class. Has anyone had the same issue?

Main class:

```
public with sharing class MainClass {
    public MainClass(){
    }

    public static void staticMethodMainclass(String sTest){
        System.debug(sTest);
    }
}
```

Subclass:

```
public with sharing class Subclass{

    public Subclass(){
        MainClass mc = new MainClass();
        Mainclass.staticMethodMainclass('testString');
    }
}
```

If you check the dependency in the Subclass, you 'll see there is no dependency and if you delete the class `MainClass` (if on a sandbox), you will not receive an error.

Comment: Can ou run thus query ¬SELECT Id,IsValid FROM ApexClass where Name='Subclass' ¬ and tell what is the value of isValid in the sandbox which allowed u to delete MainClass

Comment: The isValid value is true

{
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "ApexClass",
      "url" : "/services/data/v43.0/sobjects/ApexClass/01p1n00000P15E0AAJ"
    },
    "Id" : "01p1n00000P15E0AAJ",
    "IsValid" : true
  } ]
}

The problem is not I can delete it or not (dependent if the org is a sandbox or not), but that you can delete a class, while it is dependent to another class

Answer (score 2):

In **non-production** orgs (Sandboxes, Scratch Orgs, Developer Edition, etc), you're allowed to delete classes like this. This is normal behavior, not a bug of any sort. If you do so, your code will no longer compile or run. If this occurs anywhere in the code path of a trigger, you will be unable to insert/update/delete/undelete records of that type until the problem is resolved. You would not be allowed to do this in a Production org, as it forces a compilation cycle to run tests, and the deletion would be blocked.

Comment: is this a property which we can get in scracth orgs? Sounds useful

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Scratch orgs allow you to delete classes which have dependencies, just like sandboxes and developer orgs. There's no way to change that behavior.